# Why does this system of equation not have a solution?

Tags: equation-solving

The following set of equations leads to a solution:

```
good={
(88.20+148.02 I) a1[1]-(0.23+0.59 I) a1[2]+(0.75-0.51 I) a2[2]==0,
(-1.61*^6+5.41*^6 I) a1[1]+(1.01*^6-482339.78 I) a1[2]+(278675.43+980077.60 I) a2[2]==0,
(0.24+0.61 I) a1[2]-(0.07+0.60 I) a1[3]-(0.77-0.51 I) a2[2]+(0.66-0.41 I) a2[3]==0,
(-1.02*^6.02*+498303.20 I) a1[2]+(1.03*^6-157071.23 I) a1[3]-(304136.38+990752.54 I) a2[2]-(39378.45-1.02*^6 I) a2[3]==0,
(0.34+1.72 I) a1[3]-(1.08+1.59 I) a1[4]-(1.74-0.41 I) a2[3]+(1.64-1.13 I) a2[4]==0,
(-1.90*^6+491372.19 I) a1[3]+(1.58*^6-1.54*^6 I) a1[4]-(440860.48+1.89*^6 I) a2[3]+(1.50*^6+1.55*^6 I) a2[4]==0,
(1.13+1.62 I) a1[4]-(270040.74-103886.30 I) a1[5]-(1.67-1.17 I) a2[4]-(103886.30+270040.74 I) a2[5]==0,
(-1.60*^6.60*+1.60*^6 I) a1[4]-(8.43*^9+3.97*^9 I) a1[5]-(1.56*^6+1.58*^6 I) a2[4]+(3.97*^9-8.43*^9 I) a2[5]==99598.74,
(-6.70*^6+7.45*^6 I) a1[5]-(7.45*^6+6.70*^6 I) a2[5]+(2.86-0.03 I) a2[6]==0,
(-3.21*^11+1.08*^10 I) a1[5]-(1.08*^10+3.21*^11 I) a2[5]-(26705.31-2.92*^6 I) a2[6]==0
};

Solve[good]

(*Out:
{{a1[1]->2.4156*10^-17+1.42432*10^-15 I,
  a1[2]->3.52805*10^-13-3.63316*10^-13 I,
  a1[3]->-1.77281*10^-9+8.17473*10^-9 I,
  a1[4]->6.47414*10^-14+6.48429*10^-8 I,
  a2[2]->4.62557*10^-13+3.08395*10^-13 I,
  a2[3]->-5.16384*10^-9-3.95266*10^-9 I,
  a2[4]->-6.28108*10^-8-1.2938*10^-10 I,
  a2[5]->(-4.35079*10^-22-2.76923*10^-21 I)-(4.20554*10^-17-1. I) a1[5],
  a2[6]->(-3.16524*10^-17-2.94448*10^-16 I)-(6.30515*10^-12+8.17953*10^-12 I) a1[5]}}
*)
```

---

The following one does not:

```
bad={
(37293.91+60168.67 I) a1[1]-(0.76+0.89 I) a1[2]+(1.00-0.83 I) a2[2]==0,
(-7.54*^8+2.92*^9 I) a1[1]+(1.01*^6-1.30*^6 I) a1[2]+(1.21*^6+964780.18 I) a2[2]==0,
(0.79+0.91 I) a1[2]-(0.34+0.96 I) a1[3]-(1.02-0.86 I) a2[2]+(1.03-0.49 I) a2[3]==0,
(-1.01*^6+1.35*^6 I) a1[2]+(1.25*^6-576128.49 I) a1[3]-(1.26*^6+965705.14 I) a2[2]+(469597.86+1.23*^6 I) a2[3]==0,
(0.79+1.66 I) a1[3]-(1.83+1.27 I) a1[4]-(1.70-0.85 I) a2[3]+(1.32-1.84 I) a2[4]==0,
(-1.75*^6+1.13*^6 I) a1[3]+(852496.80-2.57*^6 I) a1[4]-(1.08*^6+1.73*^6 I) a2[3]+(2.54*^6+819179.12 I) a2[4]==0,
(1.90+1.29 I) a1[4]-(1.48*^7+2.72*^7 I) a1[5]-(1.33-1.91 I) a2[4]+(2.72*^7-1.48*^7 I) a2[5]==0,
(-830733.82+2.65*^6 I) a1[4]+(3.92*^11-1.25*^12 I) a1[5]-(2.62*^6+798336.17 I) a2[4]+(1.25*^12+3.92*^11 I) a2[5]==117698.79,
(-7.54*^7+9.13*^9 I) a1[5]-(9.13*^9+7.54*^7 I) a2[5]+(3.15-0.03 I) a2[6]==0,
(-2.79*^14+2.67*^14 I) a1[5]-(2.67*^14+2.79*^14 I) a2[5]-(23575.79-3.17*^6 I) a2[6]==0
};

Solve[bad]

(* Out: {} *)
```

---

Note that both of them complain:

> RowReduce::luc: Result for RowReduce of badly conditioned matrix {{...}} may contain significant numerical errors.

Comment: My bad, first part is matrix = input, and solve[matrix] doesn't work for that one. Second part matrix = input, and solve[matrix] finds the values for a1[1-6] and a2[1-6], i don't get why the program can read one and not the other when they have the same format just different numbers

Comment: Please do try to rewrite the question.  It's probably something that can be answered here!  Perhaps, try to limit the question to a smaller example.  What is `a1[]`?  What is `a2[]`?  Are they meant to be scalars or vectors?

Comment: The answers come as complex so is that vector? Anyway I can just add the notebook?

Comment: Please, really try to clean it up!  What is the input.  Cannot be that you inputted all of that ...

Comment: I just copy pasted what I used. Is there a way to send a notebook?

Comment: The entries of a matrix or a vector could be real or they could be complex.  A vector is represented by a list in Mathematica `a={1+I,2-I,3}`.  A matrix is a list of lists:  `A = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}`.

Comment: It results in a scalars that are complex. The program solves a bunch of these but then for some reason when it runs into this set of values it will not solve for the "matrix" it just returns {} but then when it continues the for loop i have it will solve the "matrix" again, and i'm not shifting too much as far as values so I don't understand why it won't recognize or solve for something i believe to be in the same format. I two examples onto separate notebooks and one works but the other doesn't :(

Comment: Okay.  One thing you can do is where there are 10's or 100's of digits after the decimal point, replace this by one or two digits.  That should save some space.  After that, we can make more edits to get this readable.  Thanks!

Comment: @Rookey Unfortunately, once one wades through your input, the result is actually pretty simple: the second set of equations simply **does not have a solution**. That's what `Solve` tells you when it returns `{}`. Note also that you may be running into numerical problems: you must have noticed the warnings about the poor conditioning of your system!

Answer (score 1):

`Solve` is really for exact problems, but you have many approximate "machine" numbers. You can give it exact numbers to work with by using `Rationalize`.

```
rbad = Rationalize[bad, 0];
```

This stops the warnings, but it still can't find a solution.

```
Solve[rbad]
(* {} *)
```

`Reduce` tells you that the equations are contradictory.

```
Reduce[rbad]
(* False *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon further inspection I notice that your values have different significant figures. By using SetPrecision to rewrite the number of significant figures the Solve ends up working. You can also achieve the same result using CoefficientArray[] and Inverse and dot product the matrix and matrix results. Also the first matrix results have a solution with respect to the a1[5], however I was able to find a closed solution.

Peace